# Get Text Of Closest Parent H4 Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several of these html blocks on a page in this structure

```
<div class="listing">
<h4><a href="#">Some test Entry here</a></h4>
<div class="entry clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="btn">
        Text Here                    
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have the click event on the '.entry .btn' which is firing fine. But I want to get the inner text of the 'H4 a' within the same listing block as the btn I clicked. I have tried the following but just cannot seem to get the H4 text.

```
var getTitle = $(this).parents("h4").first();
alert(getTitle.html());
```

I have also tried `closest()` but still cannot get the H4? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closest` & `parents` looks for ancestors. But, `h4` is in another children of parent `.listing`.

Try:

```
var getTitle = $(this).closest('.listing').find("h4").first();
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks I'll accept it in 10 mins when I have permission :/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly You need to traverse upwards in the DOM structure to identify the target element using `.parent()` or `.parents()` functions.

For your requirement you dont need the immediate parent hence `.parent()` is of no use instead you need to use `.parents()` to get all the ancestors in the DOM and refer the one with class selector `.listing` & finally traverse inward to find the target element `h4`.

**JS CODE:**

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
   alert($(this).parents('.listing').find('h4').html());
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/rtKZK/6/)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

use prev function in jquery

```
var getTitle = $(this).prev().find("h4").first();
alert(getTitle.html());
```